# how to make dropdown keep open on hover and disappear when leave it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

i really need help. i tried but it is still not working. i want to make a dropdown menu that will appear on hover and will disappear when leave that dropdown.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.navigation-menu').mouseenter(function(){
   $('.navigation-dropdown').addClass('visible');
  });
  $('.navigation-dropdown').mouseleave(function(){
   $('.navigation-dropdown').removeClass('visible');
  });
});
```

```css
ul{
  margin: 0;
}
.container{
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  height: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.container-dropdown{
  background-color: rgb(125,125,125)
}
.dropdown-menu{
  display: inline-block;
}
.navigation-dropdown{
  display: none;
}
.navigation-menu{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
}
.visible{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="header"> 
  <div class="container">
    <img src="" alt="">
    <div class="navigation">
      <ul>
        <li class="navigation-menu"><a href="">home</a></li>
        <li class="navigation-menu"><a href="">home</a></li>
        <li class="navigation-menu"><a href="">home</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="navigation-dropdown">
    <div class="container-dropdown">
      <ul>
        <li class="dropdown-menu">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="">
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown-menu">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="">
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown-menu">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="">
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

So, i just want to make that gray div disappear when i move my mouse leave the navigation-menu class

**my problem:** i have to move the mouse to the gray div first to make the gray div disappear. all i want is make the gray div can disappear without have to move the mouse to the gray div first

Comment: does each navigation-menu item have its own navigation-dropdown? that'd be really helpful to know if that's what you're going for

Comment: @msafi yes, it will be something like that. Can u help me to fix my problem?

Answer (score 2):

There are much better design options for you to look forward to, to get what you want. But if you just want to stick to the current layout and design, I would make a couple of changes to get what you are looking for.

```
.container{
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 0px; --to remove any space between menu title and the dropdown
}
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.navigation-menu').mouseenter(function(){
    $('.navigation-dropdown').addClass('visible');
  });
  $('.navigation-dropdown').mouseleave(function(){
    $('.navigation-dropdown').removeClass('visible');
  });

  $('.navigation-dropdown').mouseenter(function(){
      $('.navigation-dropdown').addClass('visible');
  });

  $('.navigation').mouseleave(function(){
        $('.navigation-dropdown').removeClass('visible');
  });

  $('.navigation-menu').mouseleave(function(){
        $('.navigation-dropdown').removeClass('visible');
  });
});
```

to hide dropdown menu if mouse leaves `navigation` div.

hope this helps.

Comment: Could u suggest me with another much better design that u said? Thanks

Comment: i'm sorry but ur answer not working in my code. can u give me work jsfiddle?

Comment: hey, it looks like the gray div still disappear when i move my mouse to it. actually i want to make that gray div still open on hover then that gray div will disappear when i move the mouse leave that navigation-menu class. but, my problem is i have to move the mouse to the gray div first to make the gray div disappear. all i want is make the gray div can disappear without have to move the mouse to the gray div first